# Azure Automation Resource Template can't find resources

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-automation

I've created an azure resource template which is adapted from one of the quickstart templates.

I want it to create some resources for azure automation, a runbook, a schedule, a job and a jobSchedule. The goal of this is to make a run a script which pauses SQL data warehouse instances at the end of work days.

I'm trying to run the template but getting an error that it can't create the jobSchedule and the error returns some html inside it where it can't find resources.

Template:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://schemas.microsoft.org/azure/deploymentTemplate?api-version=2015-01-01-preview#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0",
  "parameters": {
    "accountName": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The name of the Azure Automation account to deploy to."
      }
    },
    "credentialName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "SqlAutomationCredentials",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "SqlAutomationCredentials is the name of the Automation credential used in this runbook. This credential allows you to authenticate to Azure. "
      }
    },
    "userName": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The username for the Azure Automation credential."
      }
    },
    "password": {
      "type": "securestring",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The password for the Azure Automation credential."
      }
    },
    "jobId": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The GUID for the runbook job to be started."
      }
    },
    "ingestSchedulerGuid": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The GUID for schedule"
      }
    },
    "iso8601StartTime": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "ISO8601 string for the start of the schedule, has to be in the future because Azure validation says so"
      }
    },
    "subscriptionName": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "variables": {
    "runbookName": "PauseResourcesIfRunning",
    "scriptUri": "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/CBurbidge/56222bdaf181b0cca6b5f2c1e6862b1c/raw/7cf457b1eb3f5a64223cc6d3080679a0759cd731/PauseResourcesIfRunning.ps1",
    "runbookDescription": "Loops through rm resources and pauses ones which can be paused.",
    "sku": "Free",
    "scheduleLocation": "[concat('Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/', parameters('accountName'), '/schedules/sixPmWeekDaysSchedule','-',parameters('ingestSchedulerGuid'))]",
    "scheduleName": "[concat(                                            parameters('accountName'),           '/sixPmWeekDaysSchedule','-',parameters('ingestSchedulerGuid'))]",
    "endOfWorkDayScheduleName": "[concat(parameters('accountName'), '/sixPmWeekDaysSchedule','-',parameters('ingestSchedulerGuid'))]",
    "endOfWorkDayScheduleNameEnd": "[concat('sixPmWeekDaysSchedule','-',parameters('ingestSchedulerGuid'))]",
    "pauseResourcesRunbookName": "PauseResourcesIfRunning",
    "jobScheduleName": "[concat(parameters('accountName'), '/pauseResourcesAtEndOfWorkDay', '-', parameters('ingestSchedulerGuid'))]",
    "jobScheduleLocation": "[concat(parameters('accountName'), '/pauseResourcesAtEndOfWorkDay', '-', parameters('ingestSchedulerGuid'))]"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "name": "[parameters('accountName')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts",
      "apiVersion": "2015-01-01-preview",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "dependsOn": [],
      "tags": {},
      "properties": {
        "sku": {
          "name": "[variables('sku')]"
        }
      },
      "resources": [
        {
          "name": "[variables('pauseResourcesRunbookName')]",
          "type": "runbooks",
          "apiVersion": "2015-01-01-preview",
          "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
          "dependsOn": [
            "[concat('Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/', parameters('accountName'))]"
          ],
          "tags": {},
          "properties": {
            "runbookType": "Script",
            "logProgress": "false",
            "logVerbose": "false",
            "description": "[variables('runbookDescription')]",
            "publishContentLink": {
              "uri": "[variables('scriptUri')]",
              "version": "1.0.0.0"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "[parameters('credentialName')]",
          "type": "credentials",
          "apiVersion": "2015-01-01-preview",
          "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
          "dependsOn": [
            "[concat('Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/', parameters('accountName'))]"
          ],
          "tags": {},
          "properties": {
            "userName": "[parameters('userName')]",
            "password": "[parameters('password')]"
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "[variables('endOfWorkDayScheduleName')]",
          "type": "microsoft.automation/automationAccounts/schedules",
          "apiVersion": "2015-10-31",
          "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
          "dependsOn": [
            "[parameters('accountName')]",
            "[variables('pauseResourcesRunbookName')]"
          ],
          "tags": {},
          "properties": {
            "description": "6pm work days",
            "startTime": "[parameters('iso8601StartTime')]",
            "isEnabled": "true",
            "interval": "1",
            "frequency": "day",
            "advancedSchedule": {
              "weekDays": [
                "monday",
                "tuesday",
                "wednesday",
                "thursday",
                "friday"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "[variables('jobScheduleName')]",
          "type": "microsoft.automation/automationAccounts/jobSchedules",
          "apiVersion": "2015-10-31",
          "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
          "dependsOn": [
            "[parameters('accountName')]",
            "[concat('Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/', parameters('accountName'), '/runbooks/', variables('pauseResourcesRunbookName'))]",
            "[concat('Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/', parameters('accountName'), '/schedules/', variables('endOfWorkDayScheduleNameEnd'))]"
          ],
          "tags": {},
          "properties": {
            "schedule": {
              "name": "[variables('endOfWorkDayScheduleNameEnd')]"
            },
            "runbook": {
              "name": "[variables('pauseResourcesRunbookName')]"
            },
            "parameters": {
              "credentialName": {
                "value": "[parameters('credentialName')]"
              },
              "subscriptionName": {
                "value": "[parameters('subscriptionName')]"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "[parameters('jobId')]",
          "type": "jobs",
          "apiVersion": "2015-01-01-preview",
          "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
          "dependsOn": [
            "[concat('Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/', parameters('accountName'))]",
            "[concat('Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/', parameters('accountName'), '/runbooks/',variables('pauseResourcesRunbookName'))]"
          ],
          "tags": {
            "key": "value"
          },
          "properties": {
            "runbook": {
              "name": "[variables('pauseResourcesRunbookName')]"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "outputs": {}
}
```

The error is

```
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 10:16:32 - Resource microsoft.automation/automationAccounts/jobSchedules'SqlAutomation/pauseResourcesAtEndOfWorkDay-1a8de9a0-8780-47c0-9fdb-4888790f79a3' failed with message
'{
  "error": {
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN\"
\"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd\">\r\n<html
xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">\r\n<head>\r\n<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html;
charset=iso-8859-1\"/>\r\n<title>404 - File or directory not found.</title>\r\n<style
type=\"text/css\">\r\n<!--\r\nbody{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica,
sans-serif;background:#EEEEEE;}\r\nfieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;}
\r\nh1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;}\r\nh2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;}
\r\nh3{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#000000;} \r\n#header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2%
6px 2%;font-family:\"trebuchet MS\", Verdana,
sans-serif;color:#FFF;\r\nbackground-color:#555555;}\r\n#content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;}\r\n.content
-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;}\r\n-->\r\n</style>\r\n</hea
d>\r\n<body>\r\n<div id=\"header\"><h1>Server Error</h1></div>\r\n<div id=\"content\">\r\n <div
class=\"content-container\"><fieldset>\r\n  <h2>404 - File or directory not found.</h2>\r\n  <h3>The resource
you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.</h3>\r\n
</fieldset></div>\r\n</div>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n"
  }
}'
```

It's my understanding that the jobSchedule should wait for the schedule and runbook to be created because they're specified in the `dependsOn` and so i'm not sure why the resource isn't being found.

I've not seen this type of html mixed error before, previous dependency errors have been a bit more obvious what the problem is. Any ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

JobSchedules' names are Guids. You should adjust your variable's "jobScheduleName" value to be a Guid.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the error comes from the fact you are using `/` in the jobSchedule name. remove it.